# How to remove rows with NA values for a directory full of CSVs

Tags: r

I've read in a group of CSVs from my directory:

```
files <- list.files(path ="path", 
                    pattern = "*.csv", full.names = T)
```

I need to take each CSV from this list and remove any rows with NA values. After this, I still need to do this function:

```
out <- sapply(files, function(x) sum(read.csv(x)$mxpx, na.rm = FALSE))
```

How can I perform na.omit() or complete.cases() on a list of files? Or is there another approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `na.omit` on the read dataset which will remove rows having any `NA` element

```
out <- lapply(files, function(x) sum(na.omit(read.csv(x))$mxpx, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: I've done this previously, but how can I still perform the second line of code I showed? The "out" command which is similar to the line you just wrote, but I'm just taking sum of a column in each CSV.

Comment: @LoPhillips that condition is not clear to me.  Your code extracts the 'mxpx' column take the `sum` of that column

Comment: @LoPhillips I read your description as `need to take each CSV from this list and remove any rows with NA values.`. Can you please describe why the `sum` is done and what you expect from that sum

Comment: The ```sum``` of the mxpx column in each CSV from ```files``` is used to create a new dataframe that is 1-1 with the amount of CSVs from ```files```. There are some rows that have NA values in other columns, and I need those to be removed as those directly affect and skew the ```sum``` of mxpx

Comment: is this update code only removing NA values from the mxpx column? If so, then no.

Comment: @LoPhillips It removes the NA from any of the column rows and then extract the `mxpx` to get the `sum`

Comment: @LoPhilips  The extraction of column (`mxpx`) is done after the `na.omit` application

Comment: That is working, however why does the return from sapply show the data-type of each entry as well as its value rather than a data frame or a list. A Nx1 dataframe

Comment: @LoPhillips The reason is that based on your code, when you extract the `mxpx` it is a vector, then you are gettting the sum, so, in `sapply`, `simplify = TRUE` thus is coerces from list to vector.  I always used `lapply` to return a `list`

Comment: @LoPhillips I replaced with `lapply` or you can specify `simplify = FALSE` in `sapply`